# Is there way in idea format code in commit window?

Tags: java, git, svn, intellij-idea, formatting

Sometimes I need to merge branches(svn/git) in intellij idea. Sometimes it leads to resolve conflicts. And I need manually resolve conflicts in corresponding window.

But at this windows doesn't work `ctrl`+`alt`+`l` shortcut(code formatting). Also this shortcut doesn't work in commit window.

Is there way to enablle code formatting shortcut for commit window?

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with doing the code format in normal source file first, and then opening the merge tool?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen when you click merge in idea - you should resolve conflicts at first

Comment: OK...then is there anything wrong with using the merge tool first and then formatting the finished code afterwards?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I want to format only places, affected by the merge

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible the difference tool is for just checking differences - and therefore many keyboard shortcuts don't work. What you could look at is a git formatting tool - don't know if the same thing works for SVN.

[linky](https://github.com/michalrus/git-hooks-code-autoformat)

You can create a hook before commit etc and that will do the format for you. There seems several pre-check in tools out there, so take a look.